# Is there a way to check if data from a text file exist in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using a stream reader to read a text-file (.txt) data, then save it to the database. Is there a way to check if the same data exist in the database while a user is trying to read/save same text-file??

this is the  code to browse and open a text file:

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
{
    InitialDirectory = @"C:\",
    Title = "Browse Text Files",

    CheckFileExists = true,
    CheckPathExists = true,

    DefaultExt = "txt",
    Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt",
    FilterIndex = 2,
    RestoreDirectory = true,

    ReadOnlyChecked = true,
    ShowReadOnly = true
};

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

This is the code to READ AND SAVE DATA TO THE DATABASE:

```
if (textBox1.Text != "")
{
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    string message = "Data Submitted Successfully";

    string line;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=THABO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Airtime;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@textBox1.Text))
        {
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] fields = line.Split('|');

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Voucher(Currency,Nomination) VALUES (@Currency,@nomination,)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currency", fields[0].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomination", fields[1].ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

The code works fine , i want to validate (so a user can't save/read same data from a textfile to the database)

Comment: I cant read the title, its all in caps, did your caps-lock key stick down?

Comment: hey @Riley BOW-T, Please check this thread and edit the question as per standard. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if the text file contains small word or characters how you are reading in the same way you can search as well,  but if you are storing some complex data then I think it will be messy one.

Comment: You can check with ``.Contains`` e.g. ``if("file.Contains("this")){then ...}``

Answer (score 0):

If you like to find out, if it is the exact same text file, you should save additional meta informations in your database cause doing an exact comparison (depending on the size of the file) is very expensive. Depending on your scenario you could save the filename, size, creation date and / or a hash (e.g. SHA-256) of the file as additional metadata. When you get a new file you request the metadata from all files within the database where the file size is the same. Then you can do additional checks like the name, creation date or computing the hash of the new file and compare it with the hashes you already got. If at least the hash matches, than it is the same file.